# proving the function $ \frac{1}{\left(x-2\right)^{2}} $ is analytic

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series, analytic-functions

So, I want to prove that the function $ \frac{1}{\left(x-2\right)^{2}} $ is analytic in $ \mathbb{R} \setminus [2] $
What I've tried:

let $ I\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{ 2\right\}  $ be open sigment and let $ x_{0}\in I $ .
I porved by induction that the nth deriviative satisfies: $ \left(\frac{1}{\left(x-2\right)^{2}}\right)^{(n)}=\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{\left(n+1\right)!}{\left(x-2\right)^{n+2}} $

now if we'll write the function as its Taylor polymonial + the reminder (lagrange) we have:

$ \frac{1}{\left(x-2\right)^{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{\left(k\right)}\left(x_{0}\right)}{k!}\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{k}+\frac{f^{\left(n+1\right)}\left(\theta\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{n+1} $

if we'll prove thath the reminder goes to 0 when n goes to $ \infty $ we will prove the claim.

let $ \delta $ be such  $ \left(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta\right) \subseteq I $ (we will figure out later what exactly $ \delta $ have to be in order to satisfy the claims)

so, from the last claims we can say:

$ |\frac{f^{\left(n+1\right)}\left(\theta\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{n+1}|=|\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\frac{\left(n+2\right)!}{\left(\theta-2\right)^{n+3}}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{n+1}|=|\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left(n+2\right)}{\left(\theta-2\right)^{n+3}}\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{n+1}|=\frac{\left(n+2\right)|x-x_{0}|^{n+1}}{|\theta-2|^{n+1}\cdot|\theta-2|^{2}}=\frac{n+2}{|\frac{\theta-2}{x-x_{0}}|^{n+1}|\theta-2|^{2}} $

when $ \theta $ is between x and $ x_0 $

so all I have left to prove is that $ |\frac{\theta-2}{x-x_{0}}|>1 $

In that case the reminder will strive to 0 as we want.

but im having trouble choosing the right $ \delta $ in oreder to make sure this will happen.

Any ideas will help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\theta$ is between $x_0$ and $x$, you can assume
$$ \theta=(1-t)x_0+t x,t\in(0,1).$$
Let $|x-x_0|<\delta$ for some $\delta<\frac12|2-x_0|$. Then by the triangle inequality, 
$$ |\theta-2|\ge|2-x_0-t(x-x_0)|\ge|2-x_0|-t|x-x_0|>|2-x_0|-|x-x_0|>|2-x_0|-\delta $$ 
and hence, for $|x-x_0|<\delta$,
$$ \frac{|x-x_{0}|}{|\theta-2|}<\frac{\delta}{|2-x_0|-\delta}<1. $$
So 
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\bigg|\frac{f^{\left(n+1\right)}\left(\theta\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{n+1}\bigg|\\
&=&\frac{\left(n+2\right)}{|\theta-2|^{2}}\cdot\bigg(\frac{|x-x_{0}|}{|\theta-2|}\bigg)^{n+1}\\
&\le&\frac{\left(n+2\right)}{|\theta-2|^{2}}\cdot\bigg(\frac{\delta}{|2-x_0|-\delta}\bigg)^{n+1}
\end{eqnarray}
from which, you can derive
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg|\frac{f^{\left(n+1\right)}\left(\theta\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{n+1}\bigg|=0. $$